# Quaternion^2 in the symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Which is the minimum $n$ such as $Q_8\times Q_8\cong H$ with $H<S_n$?
I now that the minimum n such as $Q_8$ embeds in $S_n$ is 8, so $Q_8\times Q_8$ embeds in $S_8\times S_8< S_{16} $, but is 16 the minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general we have $\mu(G\times H)\le \mu(G)+\mu(H)$ for the minimal faithful permutation degree $\mu$. There are examples known with strict inequality, see [here](http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette/2008/Nov08/TechPaperSaunders.pdf). However, for $p$-groups we have equality. That is, we have $\mu(Q_8\times Q_8)=\mu(Q_8)+\mu(Q_8)=8+8=16$.